# how to make a div to take up the remaining height using css?

Tags: html, css

I Have the following html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="header" style="height:55px;">
<div id="menu" style="height:85px;">
<div id="container" style="height:100%;">
<body>
</html>
```

but container div is not taking the full height.its takes the height to cover the content within it.

Comment: You didn't close any of your div tags.

Comment: Just set a default height for your divs and only override the height in a div where you want a specific height.

Comment: Just set your div to 100%

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to achieve that

```
#container {
    height: calc(100% - 140px);
    background: #f00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EDmDf/)

Here, I am adding up `55px` of `#header` and `85px` of `#menu` which sums up to `140px` and than we deduct that from `100%`. Also, avoid using inline CSS. Just make sure you set the parents `height` to `100%` as well else the solution will fail.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

---

The browser support is pretty decent as well.

[image]

<sup>Credits for support chart : [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)</sup>

Comment: This is a good solution and I'd be inclined to use it. But it seems that the OP does not fully understand some things and you really should have a fallback when using things like this, and it appears that the OP does not know how to implement this fallback (hence this question).

Comment: IE 9 had really buggy support. I would say 10 and above. +1 though, good answer :)

Comment: Buggy support in safari?

Comment: @Mr.Alien You're not showing any -1 on the count on my end?

Comment: @AshleyMedway he just took back :)

Comment: @AshleyMedway yes, when you use `background-position` but that's not the case here :) and thank you...

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags must be closed.

For example,
`<div>` must be followed by `</div>` there a few exceptions to this such as the `<input />` and `<img />` tags which are considered self closing.

Here is a slightly better version of your code: http://jsbin.com/uyIwERE/4/edit

Comment: This will create a scrollbar for the overflowing 140px.